# Preventing x scroll on web mobile browser

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I run my browser on mobile and what I get on one page , is a huge y scroll to the right.
So I used this:

```
   body{
    overflow-y: scroll !important;    
       overflow-x: hidden !important;
    }
```

That didnt help, and when I run the site on the browser..such an effect doesnt happen. Is there any way to disable y scrolling? perhaps that will also be suitable on the browser for the mobile!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to disable `y` scrolling and you are disabling `x` here

```
html, body {  /*You probably wont need !important too */
   overflow-y: hidden !important;    
   overflow-x: auto !important; /*Or you can use scroll value as well*/
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/npn9K/)

> Note: If you are disabling your scroll, users wont be able to scroll
>   vertically at all..content overflowed out of the viewport will be
>   hidden